# Remove hash from one page template url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in a one page scrolling template that used a plugin (smoothscroll.js) I try to remove hash from url after user click on link but unfortunately I cant do it. I follow this type of question on stackoverflow but not working for me.

My code is below:

index:

```
<li><a href="#meet-us" class="page-scroll">Meet Us</a></li>
```

JS:

```
$('a.page-scroll').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();     
       if(history.pushState) {
         history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
       }
    return false;
});
```

How to remove just `#`. now url `localhost/main/#meet-us` but I need `localhost/main/meet-us` this type of.

Big appreciated if help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href').replace("#", ""));
```

Comment: Hi **@Linus Gustav Larsson Thiel** I'm really appreciated for your nice work. now create one problem if I directly copy peste `localhost/main/meet-us` this url then showing server error. click work properly

Comment: Well you need to make sure the server can handle that URL, otherwise it's not of much use to push it to history...!

Comment: If you don't know about that, you should probably just leave the history API (`pushState` and friends) alone and just use the anchor tags (`#`) as they are - that's what they are designed for, after all.